# How to Install a quiz bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I want to install a quiz-bundle ([from this link](https://packagist.org/packages/lms42/quiz-bundle#dev-master)) so I added this bundle as a dependency in the composer.json file

like this :

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        //...
        "lms42/quiz-bundle":"dev-master"

    },
```

then I run `composer update` command in the command line

After this in installation instructions in order to complete the installation of this bundle :

1/ I should Register the namespace in autoload.php 
like this :

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    ...
    'Smirik'           => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
));
```

but when I open app/autoload.php I found it like this

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

#### Question 1/ how can I change this file to Register the namespace ?

2/ I should add this code to config.yml

```
fos_user:
      db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb'
      firewall_name: main
      user_class: Smirik\QuizBundle\Entity\User
      group:
          group_class: Smirik\QuizBundle\Entity\Group

...
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
      resources:
        - 'SmirikQuizBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

But in my app/config/config.yml file I have this :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UsersBundle\Entity\User
    service:
            user_manager: pugx_user_manager
    registration:
            confirmation:
                enabled: true
    from_email:
            address:        noreply@openagency.org
            sender_name:    Demo App
//...
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
```

#### Question 2 / should I change my config.yml or no ?

Comment: The installation doc seems very old (the instructions are about the sf 2.0 version when composer don't exists yet) so the first step about autoloading is done by composer (you can skip) you need to do the work starting from the config.yml section. I take a look at the composer.json and seem not weel done: missing dependency'bundle... so take care of this...

Comment: And I also think this bundle won't be compatible with current Symfony versions.

Comment: Perhaps, you should ask the maintainer instead. I've opened an issue notifying him that perhaps he should deprecate the package: https://github.com/lms42/SmirikQuizBundle/issues/3

Comment: Thank you all for your replies